# Difference between Cloudera Hive, Horton Works Hive and MapR Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr

Is there any difference in different distributions of Hive(I believe there will be because every vendor is giving their own implementation on top of Apache Hive). If there is a difference which distribution Hive is good performance wise. Can someone please provide the information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are hive versions which are compatible with specific verions of Hadoop.

These vendors (Cloudera,Horton,MapR) provides hadoop clusters.So the hive version varies depending upon hadoop version they used for setting up the cluster.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_SupportedHiveVersions.html

Comment: Hi @Taha Kashaf Haider Naqvi, Thanks for the response. If I understand your response correct these vendors only provide Hadoop cluster and won't make any changes to Apache Hive and will give it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

What is your use case, exactly? It's possible that Hive won't give you the "good performance" you need, regardless of the distribution you choose.

Most people don't choose Hive for its performance (especially in multi-user situations) but rather for its fault tolerance.